# Plotting a segment of data with Flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm plotting simple stripcharts with [Flot](https://github.com/flot/flot). How might I implement a scrolling window?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnpb3/2/)

So say in ten minutes time, I have ~1000 data points, but I only want to display the most recent 100. How do I go about doing that? It needs to be nondestructive, because I want to implement a scroll bar so I can scroll through the data, while only seeing 100 data points at a time.

I tried adjusting the xaxis... no good.

```
// Why doesn't this work?
var options = plot.getOptions();
options.xaxis.min = data[i].length - 100;
options.xaxis.max = data[i].length;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool plots.

You are looking for:

```
    var options = plot.getOptions();
    options.xaxes[0].min = data[i].length - 100;
    options.xaxes[0].max = data[i].length;
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cnpb3/4/).

Comment: That's great! Thanks! Tell me, what's the difference? It feels like those should be identical. If you log `options` there is both `xaxis` and `xaxes`.

Comment: Before flot had multiple axes support I believe they were configured using `xaxis` and `yaxis`.  When multiple axes support was added, it became an array of `xaxes` and the `xaxis` config option because a way of setting properties for all the `axes`.  The "living" config, though has shifted into the array.